# Kendo UI get data from dataSource using Foreign Key

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Greeting All,

Let assume I had a grid [like this](https://dojo.telerik.com/UWanaJUv). But in `columns>field` `values: categories` I want to get the data from the dataSource *(below)* and display into dropdownlist. How to achieve this method?

```
var categories = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "./getCategories.php",
        type: "POST"
    }
},
});
```

and the output will be like this

```
[{"categoriesID":"92","categoriesName":"BOOKING"},
{"categoriesID":"1","categoriesName":"SYSTEM"},
{"categoriesID":"57","categoriesName":"SYSTEM1"},
{"categoriesID":"2","categoriesName":"SYSTEM2"},
{"categoriesID":"55","categoriesName":"TEST"},
{"categoriesID":"56","categoriesName":"TRY"}]
```

p/s: my category column will display categoriesID, but I want to appear categoriesName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are asking about an editor template. When you want a custom control instead of the default editor the grid offers you should use the [editor property of column](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editor).
Editor templates will map the the value back to your model Category Id.

Also you should use the [client template](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.template) propert of column, if you want the column to show some other value than the one it is mapped to. In your case grid column is mapped to Category Id but you want to show the Category Name.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>

var ProductDataSrc = [
{"ProductID":"3" , "categoriesID":"56","categoriesName":"TRY"},
{"ProductID":"6" , "categoriesID":"55","categoriesName":"TEST"},
{"ProductID":"2" , "categoriesID":"92","categoriesName":"BOOKING"},
{"ProductID":"62" , "categoriesID":"1","categoriesName":"SYSTEM"},
{"ProductID":"23" , "categoriesID":"2","categoriesName":"SYSTEM2"},
{"ProductID":"12" , "categoriesID":"57","categoriesName":"SYSTEM1"} ];


var categoryDataSrc = [
{"categoriesID":"92","categoriesName":"BOOKING"},
{"categoriesID":"1","categoriesName":"SYSTEM"},
{"categoriesID":"57","categoriesName":"SYSTEM1"},
{"categoriesID":"2","categoriesName":"SYSTEM2"},
{"categoriesID":"55","categoriesName":"TEST"},
{"categoriesID":"56","categoriesName":"TRY"}];


$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "categoriesID", title:"Category",
    template: "<strong>#: categoriesName # </strong>",
    editor: function(container, options) {
     var input = $("<input/>");
     input.attr("name", options.field);
     input.appendTo(container);
     input.kendoDropDownList({
       dataValueField:  "categoriesID",
       dataTextField: "categoriesName",
       dataSource: categoryDataSrc
     });
    }  
  },
  { command: ["edit", "destroy"] }],
  dataSource: ProductDataSrc,
  editable: "inline"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I try to duplicate with my current situation [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/uHoKeYaP) .But i don't know how to make it display **categoriesName** in the column. I try to use template, but it just make it worst. It only appear when edit.

Comment: @Nixoderm Your Grid data source should get the foreign key text value you intend to display in the grid column so you must change your data source model to include category name. I have updated the script above for your reference.